# Export data DataGridView to Excel

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-excel

I'm creating a class to export data from `DataGridView` to Excel file. When I invoke the method I got an empty excel sheet. However it does work when I insert directly the method inside the code without using a class.

Any idea why this class doesn't work.

```
class ExportToExcel
{
       public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp =  new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook ExcelBook;
       public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet ExcelSheet;
       DataGridView dt = new DataGridView();

       public  DataGridView Dt { set { this.dt = value; } }


       public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exportToExcel(DataGridView dt)
        {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;



        ExcelBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        ExcelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)ExcelBook.ActiveSheet;
        //export header
        for (i = 1; i <= this.dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ExcelSheet.Cells[1, i] = this.dt.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        //export data
        for (i = 1; i <= this.dt.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ExcelSheet.Cells[i + 1, j] = dt.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value;
            }
        }


            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
            ExcelSheet = null;
            ExcelBook = null;
            ExcelApp = null;

         return ExcelApp;

    }
}
```

---

```
private void exportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ExportToExcel ex = new ExportToExcel();
        ex.exportToExcel(dtReport2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exportToExcel(DataGridView dt)

It looks like your method is referring both to this.dt (class variable) and a local version of dt (the one you pass into the method as a parameter.)

Based on your code - the class version of dt is never being set to anything.

I'm not sure exactly how you want your class to work, but you may want to consider setting dt and not passing another gridview into your exportToExcel method.

```
 private void exportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ExportToExcel ex = new ExportToExcel();
    ex.dt = dtReport2; // set the public class variable here
    ex.exportToExcel(); // removed the datagrid from your parameter in the exportToExcel() method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! I deleted the keyword "this" and I changed the variable name and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  use these codes its perfectly working
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml

 Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
        For i = 0 To TAPDataGridView.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To TAPDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To TAPDataGridView.Columns.Count
                   xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = TAPDataGridView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
              xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = TAPDataGridView(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next


        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\P A R\Documents\?.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        MsgBox("You can find the file D:\Todays_record_excel.xlsx")
    End Sub
```

for it to work add a new reference find the microsoft excel